# Using Visual Basic to copy max conditional array given changing cell references

Tags: vba, excel

I have a good understanding of formulas, but a limited knowledge of Visual Basic. I'm trying to make a training spreadsheet. Excel is probably a difficult challenge for this task, but it's what I know and what I've got. I have one tab with everyone's names and dates they were trained (which I'm using with a badge reader to "log" the entry). I then have a "Tracker" tab which has everyone's name on the rows and the training name on the top of the columns. I used an array to find the maximum date given the name and Training, which I setup to change as I move down and across the sheet. I've attached my formula for reference.

```
{=IF(MAX(IF('Badge Reader Archived'!$D:$D=Tracker!$E12&", "&$F12,IF('Badge Reader Archived'!$J:$J=Tracker!I$8,'Badge Reader Archived'!$H:$H)))=0,"",MAX(IF('Badge Reader Archived'!$D:$D=Tracker!$E12&", "&$F12,IF('Badge Reader Archived'!$J:$J=Tracker!I$8,'Badge Reader Archived'!$H:$H))))}
```

The problem I'm having is that I have so many entries that if I place the formulas everywhere I want, the sheet crashes. I tried to use a macro to copy paste, then paste values. It worked for one or two entries, but if it was too large I couldn't get it to work. I think I can piece meal the Macro so that it will make very small copy and pastes and not crash Excel. I'm wondering if anyone knows a better cleaner way to accomplish this. Here's my macro in all it's ugliness. I tried to only paste 100 times and it still failed on me.

```
Sub Refresh()
'
' Refresh Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = False
'

Range("I12").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I13:I100").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Range("I12").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I100:I200").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I100").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

 Range("I12").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I300:I400").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I300").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False



Range("I12").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I400:I500").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I400").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Range("I12").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I500:I600").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I500").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Range("I12").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I600:I700").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I600").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Range("I12").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I700:I808").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I700").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: You need to limit the data set on your array formulas to only those cells with data, do not use full column references, and I bet you will be able to use the formula.  For instance instead of `'Badge Reader Archived'!$D:$D` use `'Badge Reader Archived'!$D$1:$D$5000`  The closer you get to the actual number of rows in the data set the quicker the formula and the less taxing on the calc it will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have thought about it, but I didn't think about how much work it's doing search the entire column. I changed to to 50,000 (for good measure) and the macro was successful.  Thanks again!